# Get JSON in POST request

Tags: java, json, post, request

I am sending a POST request:

```
var arr = { State: 'Moscow', Age: 25 };
var url = "/google/modifiedPolygon";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: arr,
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function() {
      alert("msg");
  }
});
```

And handling from backend as:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/modifiedPolygon",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public void modifiedPolygon(@RequestBody JSONObject data, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

But I am getting following error:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'State': was expecting
>   ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: You're also failing to take advantage of Spring's usefulness by passing `JSONObject` and `HttpServletRequest` instead of letting it transform into data-specific classes.

Comment: @chrylis can you exlplain little further

Answer (score 0):

It looks like State is a boolean type on the service side, But you are sending String value as State. So verify the datatype for State the service exepcting.

Comment: I am just sending sample data from frontend and trying to print it in backend. There is no datatype for State. Earlier I wrote City in place of state it was saying Unrecognized token 'City'

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this,

```
var arr = { state: 'Moscow', age: 25 };
var url = "/google/modifiedPolygon";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: { "dataValue": JSON.stringify(arr)},
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function() {
      alert("msg");
  }
});
```

now, you can get "dataValue" in backEnd from body param.

Comment: It is giving following error
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'dataValue': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: yes, it should be like this
data: {" dataValue": JSON.stringify(arr)},

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following Java implementation and it seems working.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/modifiedPolygon",method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> modifiedPolygon(@RequestBody JSONObject data, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(data,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

First test with POSTMAN or curl, if issue persists, try with this.

```
var arr = { state: 'Moscow', age: 25 };
var url = "/google/modifiedPolygon";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  type: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify(arr),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  success: function() {
      alert("msg");
  }
});
```

And please enable the CORS filters.

Here are the working snapshot.

[image]

[image]

Add this dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.1</version>
      </dependency>
```

Please find the java code changes here

https://github.com/supun/Shopping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shopping/controller/MainController.java

Comment: OK has red line under it says OK cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: Just import that class form spring library

Comment: which class, it is not showing any class in suggestion

Comment: Find the import statement from this class.  https://github.com/supun/Shopping/blob/master/src/main/java/com/shopping/controller/ProductRestController.java

Comment: Now it is showing following error:
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field "State" (class org.json.JSONObject), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])

Comment: how and why to enable cors filters? and what are headers used in postman?

Comment: If the request is not hitting to server, you need to enable CORS. In this case you do not need to do so since the request is already sending. 

Header : Content-Type = application/json